# how to stop sliding by dragging the main page to right

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I have done MenuSlider but i just want to slide when  actionBar home button is clicked how to do so i m not getting any idea to resolve this issue      since i have to add 4 tabs then navigation to them seems difficult

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();


    Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_bar);  

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //actionBar.setTitle("Action Bar");
    actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.transparent);
    //actionBar.setSubtitle("http://www.android.com");
    actionBar.addOnMenuVisibilityListener(this);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(d);


    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getOverflowMenu();

    setBehindContentView(R.layout.left_tab);
    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);
    slideMenu = getSlidingMenu();
    slideMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    slideMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    slideMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    //slideMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    slideMenu.setBehindOffset(80);
    slideMenu.setFadeDegree(0.99f);

    inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    //item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_tab, null);}
}
```

Comment: Its being to late to reply, maybe you have already resolved this issue but still for the sake of SO new members I am posting this answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Changing

```
slideMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
```

to

```
slideMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.ABOVE);
```

> touchModeAbove - an enum that designates what part of the screen is touchable when the above view is showing. Margin means only the left margin. Fullscreen means the entire screen. Default is margin.

---

#### Simple Example

```
public class SlidingExample extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(R.string.attach);
    // set the content view
    setContentView(R.layout.content);
    // configure the SlidingMenu
    SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
}

}
```

#### XML Usage

If you decide to use SlidingMenu as a view, you can define it in your xml layouts like this:

```
<com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
    xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slidingmenulayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    sliding:viewAbove="@layout/YOUR_ABOVE_VIEW"
    sliding:viewBehind="@layout/YOUR_BEHIND_BEHIND"
    sliding:touchModeAbove="margin|fullscreen"
    sliding:behindOffset="@dimen/YOUR_OFFSET"
    sliding:behindWidth="@dimen/YOUR_WIDTH"
    sliding:behindScrollScale="@dimen/YOUR_SCALE"
    sliding:shadowDrawable="@drawable/YOUR_SHADOW"
    sliding:shadowWidth="@dimen/YOUR_SHADOW_WIDTH"
    sliding:fadeEnabled="true|false"
    sliding:fadeDegree="float"
    sliding:selectorEnabled="true|false"
    sliding:selectorDrawable="@drawable/YOUR_SELECTOR"/>
```

> ## This class was deprecated in API level 17. This class is not supported anymore. It is recommended you base your own implementation on the source code for the Android Open Source Project if you must use it in your application.

Output:

[image]